# keyup event not triggered inside twitter bootstrap modal form

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap.

I have created a modal window and it gets called as expected.

Inside this modal, there is a form:

```
<div id="initialSurveyInfo" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalId" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="modalId">Initial Survey Information</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="surveyTitle">Survey Title :</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="surveyTitle">
                    <span class="help-inline muted"><span class="char-limit">36</span> character(s) left</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="surveyDesc">Description:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <textarea rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</a>
        <a href="/createSurvey" class="btn btn-primary continue">Continue</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the input, the user is restricted to only 36 characters. Beyond 36 characters, I want to disable the "continue" button.
I have the current character count right next to the input.

My jQuery code to handle this is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var calculate = function() {
        var chararcters = $("#surveyTitle").val().length;

        var remaining = 36 - characters;

        if (remaining >= 0) {
            $(".char-limit").val(remaining);
            if ($(".continue").hasClass("disabled") === true) {
                $(".continue").removeClass("disabled");
            }
        } else {
            $(".continue").addClass("disabled");
        }
    };

    $("#surveyTitle").keyup(calculate);
    $("#surveyTitle").change(calculate);
});
```

Unfortunately, the keyup() and change() events / methods are not being fired. Thus the remaining character count is not going down and neither is the "Continue" button being disabled when the character count is exceeded.
I replaced `keyup` with `on('keyup', function)` - this does not work either.

Any idea on how I can respond to the keyup events - the main question would be how to change the "# of characters left" in such a case?

I am using AngularJS too but I do not think it is affecting anyway (The modal window is in a view template that AngularJS loads based on some previous action)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally found the solution. @sasi's solution is partially correct.

Basically, the issue is discussed here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2380

The solution is the following:
Replace

```
$("#surveyTitle").keyup(calculate);
```

with

```
$("body").on('keyup', "#surveyTitle", calculate);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
on('keyup','#surveyTitle', function) {

}


$("body").on('keyup', "#surveyTitle", calculate);
```

have you tried like this..?

Comment: Almost correct. I needed to add the `$('body')` selector to the on method. See my answer below.

Comment: Yes. It works. I followed up on your lead and found that github issue which also mentioned the correct way to do it.